# convert all keys of object to variable in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, variable-assignment

In react you can do something like

`const obj = {
   thing: 'a',
}`

then `const { thing } = obj` is a shorthand for `const thing = obj.thing`

**is there a way to convert all object key/value pairs at once?**

`Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
    const eval(key) = obj[key];
}`

something like that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do it is by destructuring the object, but you will need to know your object properties for that:

```
const { prop1, prop2, prop3 } = obj;
```

And by the way your example with ".map" won't work because you are creating a local constants which won't be accessible outside that function.

Comment: To add to this you can destruct an object of an object like so: const { prop1: { prop2 }} = obj; would output prop2.